# Cannot log into Area 51 with Google account

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, login

Whenever I try to login to [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com) using "*log in with Google*" I got the following exception:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>
> An unexpected error occurred while logging in. It's not you, it's us.
>   This is our fault. Detailed information about this error has
>   automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

[image: Error image]

I'm using the same log in way that I use for other Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: Do you happen to have HTTPS Everywhere plugin? If so, disable it and try again.

Comment: No. I even tried this on many browsers with/out private browsing mode

Comment: Maybe you had your account merged at some point? Anyway, afraid only SE staff can help. Until then you can try adding new login (even here) and try using it there as well. (e.g. SE OpenID)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a problem with your account on our end. Basically, there was a record in one of our databases that pointed to the wrong user id on Area 51 for your account.

I fixed that up, so you should be able to log in now.

Comment: Thanks, I logged in but maybe I've lost some of my contributions. Anyway thank you, it's not that important contribution

Comment: Hi there, I think I am having a similar problem, posted here: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27509/i-cant-log-into-the-main-site. Any chance you can help?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue with Area 51. This may not be isolated. (ongoing for a week now).

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I’ll check it out tomorrow. If you don’t hear back by the end of the day (NYC time :)), ping me here again.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs You should be all set. Let me know if you still can't access A51.

Comment: You're great! Fixed it up, thanks!